# Spacing between bullet list rows

Tags: html, css

How do I set the spacing between bullet lists?

- asdfasdf
- asdf23223

I want to put a little more space between the first and second rows like

```
<ul>
    <li>asdfasdf</li>
<p />
    <li>asdf23223</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Add `top` and `bottom` padding to the `li`s, like so:

```
ul li { padding: 5px 0px; }
```

And **take out that crazy looking `<p />` tag**.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aFED2/

Comment: Inline Styling does work - but I have found the above solution to be the best for security.  CSS injection attacks can occur with in line styling and things like NPM Helmet put restrictions on Inline Styling.

Answer (score 13):

You might be able to do something like this:

```
<ul style="line-height:1.4;">
```

Comment: This will adjust the line height between every two **lines** not **rows/bullets**. So I guess it's best to do something like: `<ul style=" margin-bottom: 5px;">`

Answer (score 10):

I'm assuming `<p />` tag is just a typo, it shouldn't be there ;)

Add this into your `<head>` tag:

```
<style>
    ul li { margin-bottom: 10px; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `line-height` This will put spacing above and below the text.

Comment: The issue with this solution is that it also adds space between the lines of the same bullet point

Answer (score 1):

**Use the CSS as:**

```
li { padding: 10px 0px 0px; }
li:first-child { margin-bottom: 0px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just use the  so that it will not mess with the styles of all of my other pages when using html and php.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pre` tag. No need for the css

```html
<ul>
  <pre>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
    <li>Baz</li>
    </pre>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a `margin-bottom` for your list item

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6tcpd/